# weighted average Jensen style limits

Tags: limits

I am teaching Jensen's inequality and one of my students came up with the question below. I am not sure whether it is true or not.

Let $(w_n)_{n\ge 0}$, $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be two sequences of positive terms, and let $f$ be a continuous increasing function on $(0, \infty)$. We know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} w_n =0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n =1$.  Prove or disprove that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{w_0f(x_0)+w_1f(x_1)+\ldots+w_nf(x_n)}{w_0+w_1+\ldots+w_n} =\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}f\left( \frac{w_0x_0+w_1x_1+\ldots+w_nx_n}{w_0+w_1+\ldots+w_n}\right) 
\end{equation*}

Comment: Continously increasing for each $x_k$?

Comment: The function $f$ is independent of both sequences $w_n$ and $x_n$. It is simply continuous and increasing.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I misread it as a function with multiple in-values first.

Comment: @ Chappers thank you very much; it is a nice construction.

Comment: @user84909 Thank you. Just FYI, you need to put no spaces in the @ thing: it doesn't work as a notification otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's false. Let's look at an example that we can compute exactly. Let $0<r<1$ and $f(x)=x^2$, and $w_k=r^k$, $x_k=1-r^k$. Clearly these satisfy all the required properties. Now,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n w_k x_k= \sum_{k=0}^{n} r^k(1-r^k) = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}-\frac{1-r^{2n+2}}{1-r^2}, \\
\sum_{k=0}^n w_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} r^k = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r},
 $$
so the right-hand side, pre-limit, is
$$ \left( 1-\frac{1-r^{2n+2}}{(1+r)(1-r^{n+1})} \right)^2. $$
Clearly taking the limit gives
$$ \left( 1-\frac{1}{1+r} \right)^2 = 1-\frac{2}{1+r}+\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}. $$

Now, the left-hand side has
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} w_k f(x_k) = \sum_{k=0}^n r^k(1-r^k)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^n (r^k-2r^{2k}+r^{3k}) = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}-2\frac{1-r^{2(n+1)}}{1-r^2}+\frac{1-r^{3(n+1)}}{1-r^3}, $$
so the ratio is
$$ 1-2\frac{1-r^{2n+2}}{(1+r)(1-r^{n+1})}+\frac{1-r^{3n+3}}{(1+r+r^2)(1-r^{n+1})}, $$
and taking the limit gives
$$ 1-\frac{2}{1+r}+\frac{1}{1+r+r^2}. $$
But then
$$ \frac{1}{1+r+r^2} >\frac{1}{1+2r+r^2} = \frac{1}{(1+r)^2}, $$
so the left-hand side is not equal to the right-hand side.

---

My suspicion is that the truth of the statement depends on whether $\sum_k w_k$ diverges, although I haven't a proof.

Comment: ↑ That is a nice example. I was also looking at $f(x)=x^2$, but I did not come up with the $x_k$ and $w_k$...